# Dynamic named parameters in pg-promise

Tags: node.js, pg-promise

I have a patch endpoint in my REST API where every body parameter is optional. What is the best way of implementing it without checking each parameter manually?

```
db.none("update tasks set title=$1, description=$2, value=$3 where id=$4",
    [req.body.title, req.body.description, parseInt(req.body.value), req.params.id])
    .then(function () {
        res.status(200)
            .json({
                status: "success",
                message: "Updated task"
            });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        return next(err);
    });
```

Comment: Your query contains 4 parameters, while the you pass in only 3 values. This doesn't look right. You need to fix your example first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use methods in the [helpers](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html) namespace:

**static declarations**

```
const optional = name => ({name, skip: col => !col.exists});

const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet([
    optional('title'),
    optional('description'),
    optional('value')
], {table: 'tasks'});
```

**generating the query and executing it:**

```
const update = pgp.helpers.update(req.body, cs) + ' WHERE id = ' + req.params.id;

db.none(update)
    .then(function () {
        res.status(200)
            .json({
                status: "success",
                message: "Updated task"
            });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        return next(err);
    });
```

In addition, you might want to use option `emptyUpdate` of method [helpers.update](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.update), to check that at least one column is being set, to avoid invalid query generation request and an error thrown.

Comment: can you briefly explain or point me to the right direction so I understand the static declaration part?

Comment: @Shakur Static - means you declare it only once. The links to all the types with API and documentation - I gave you from the beginning. If you want more examples - there are plenty on StackOverflow, if you search for `pg-promise ColumnSet`: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=pg-promise%20ColumnSet